# Creating a dynamic web page using AngularJS, WCF Service and SQL Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, angularjs

I want to create a web application and I am exploring how I could do this. So I came across AngularJS. I want to use WCF Service and SQL Server in my application also. I am trying to find what AngularJS, WCF Service, SQL Server can do for me because I do not want change technologies in the middle of my project after discovering that AngularJS cannot do things which I want my application to do.

So, my question is can AngularJS help me create Static web pages and Dynamic web pages? 
I can start my project in **ASP.NET MVC** but I want to explore [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and want to find out what it is.

My project is about

1. Sending E-mails
2. Displaying content from database (in any manner using Ajax)
3. Voice chat, Video chat, Text chat
4. Can contain Javascript, jQuery, CSS, HTML5

Tell me something about it. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague, but I'd suggest using Microsoft WebAPI instead of WCF or even ASP MVC, due to the from the ground up RESTful design of WebAPI and much easier configuration.

Using this approach, you'll still be able to query SQL Server in C# using WebAPI, so you won't need to switch your database.

There's very little documentation by comparison for querying non-RESTful web services, so you'll gain a huge advantage in terms of tutorials, blogs, etc. by going this route.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below for your questions:

1. Can AngularJS help me create Static web pages and Dynamic web pages?

Yes certainly it can. Check it out at the [official website](http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs)

2.Sending E-mails

This should be the server side responsibility using an e-mail client, for instance [SMTP client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

3.Displaying content from database (in any manner  using Ajax)

Yes, it certainly can.

4.Voice chat, Video chat, Text chat
Try [WebRTC](https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/home) first to see if it's sufficient for your tasks

5.Can contain Javascript, jQuery, CSS, HTML5

Yes, you can use whatever you want as long as you are sure about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following guidelines will help you.

1. When you create the project select WebApi template.
2. Then include angularjs files in the scripts folder.
3. Use cshtml files,but do as you in html file.
4. Use angular client side mvc features to build your app fast and performance.
5. Use the angular http service to call webapi methods.
6. All the c# specfic features build in the webapi.